# Mac OSX11 (BigSur) - changing Region / Country (locale) via appleScript

Tags: applescript, locale

I need to automate the change of locale (Region/Country) for format purpose from:
Region: Americas
Country: United States

[image: United States]

to
Region: Europe
Country: Spain
[image]

So I have the following code, which seems to work up to the point where the system asks to restart the machine (or not).
[image]

```
property theSettings : {"", ""}

set settings1 to {"Americas", "United States"}
set settings2 to {"Europe", "Spain"}


if running of application "System Preferences" then
    
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if



repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat



tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Language" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.Localization"
    activate
    
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell window "Language & Region" of process "System Preferences"
        if (value of pop up button "Region:" of tab group 1) is "United States" then
            set theSettings to settings2
        else
            
            set theSettings to settings1
        end if
        
        set {theRegion, theCountry} to theSettings
        tell pop up button "Region:" of tab group 1
            delay 0.25
            click
            delay 0.25
            click menu item theRegion of menu 1
            delay 0.25
            click menu item theCountry of menu 1 of menu item theRegion of menu 1
        end tell
        
    end tell
    
    delay 1
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    tell sheet 1 of window "Language & Region" of process "System Preferences"
        delay 1
        keystroke tab
        delay 1
        keystroke return
    end tell
    
end tell
```

In the script above, after switching locale, I am trying to click the button Don't Restart. But this does not work as the sheet window  does not seem to be active.

Any idea on how to save the settings?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is, at that point the *sheet* is *modal* and typically requires physical intervention. In other words, based on its current appearance, normally one would either press **enter/return** *key* to accept the *default* or use the **mouse** to click either **Don’t Restart** or **Cancel** as *tabbing* in not active by default in this use case.

However, if the **[√] Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls** *checkbox* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** is checked, which it is not by default, then one could simply press the **space bar** as **Don’t Restart** would have focus even though **Restart Now** would be, by default, solid blue.

To get past the modality of the situation, one would have to add code that would programmatically check to see that the aforementioned *checkbox* is checked, and if not check it.

In addition to the check and taking action if necessary, the modifications to your existing *code* are as follows:

**In between:**

```
repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat
```

**And:**

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Language" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.Localization"
    activate
end tell
```

**Add:**

```
--  # Get the fully qualified POSIX pathname of the target .plist file.

set thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
    the POSIX path of ¬
        (path to preferences from user domain as string) & ¬
    ".GlobalPreferences.plist"

--  # Get the value of AppleKeyboardUIMode to determine if the
--  # 'Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls'
--  # checkbox is checked on the System Preferences >  
--  # Keyboard > Shortcuts tab.

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell the property list file thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
        set keyboardNavigation to the value of ¬
            the property list item "AppleKeyboardUIMode"

if keyboardNavigation = 0 then
    --  # Check the checkbox.
    my toggleKeyboardNavigation()
end if
```

**And to the end of the *script* add:**

```
--  # Handler #

--  # Toggles checkbox: 'Use keyboard navigation 
--  # to move focus between controls'

on toggleKeyboardNavigation()
    tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of ¬
            pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell front window of ¬
            application process "System Preferences"
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists checkbox 1 of tab group 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            click checkbox 1 of tab group 1
        end tell
    end tell
end toggleKeyboardNavigation
```

**After making the aforementioned changes, then starting with:**

```
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

**Replace it and the ensuing `tell` *block* with:**

```
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
end ignoring
delay 1
key code 49 --  # space key
```

**Then after the `end tell` of the primary `tell application "System Events"` *block*, the one just below the previous *code* change, add the following:**

```
repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

if keyboardNavigation = 0 then
    --  # Uncheck the checkbox if it
    --  # was previously unchecked.
    my toggleKeyboardNavigation()
    delay 0.2
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
end if
```

---

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown herein to check to see if **[] Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** is checked, can be done differently by opening to that *pane* and ascertaining whether of not it's checked and act accordingly. The reason I've added the *code* for it as is, is because I've used it to reset that *checkbox* later on in the script in the past. If the *checkbox* is already checked then one doesn't have to see the extra changing of *panes*.

Comment: @Thierry Beliere, Did this resolve your issue?